# Detect GPIO button press within time limit

Tags: python, pi-2, rpi.gpio, pi-3

I've got a photo booth program I'm working on that takes the photo of the user and displays it on the screen for 5-10 seconds. At the end of that 5-10 seconds, I'd like the booth to reset *unless* a particular GPIO button has been pressed.

I was able to find an analogous code snippet to what I'd like to do, but I can't seem to make it take GPIO.input() or GPIO event detection into account. Trying GPIO.wait_for_event, just causes the process to hang while it waits for input. It's important that the default operation is to just reset the photobooth for the next person (without intervention).

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from threading import Thread

answer = None
def check():
    time.sleep(5)
    if answer == 'y':
        print "\nSounds good, I'll send it to the queue!"
        time.sleep(1)
    print "\nMoving on..."

Thread(target=check).start() 
answer = raw_input("You have 5 seconds. Print? [y/n]: ")
```

Answer (score 2):

There will be hundreds of ways of achieving what you want.

Here is my take.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

BUTTON=23

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit(0)

stop = time.time() + 60

while time.time() < stop:

   # Put code here

   print("press button to print photo")

   if pi.wait_for_edge(BUTTON, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, 5): # 5 second t/o
      # Button pressed
      print("printing photo")
   else:
      # No button press
      print("dumping photo")

   # Put code here

   time.sleep(1)

pi.stop()
```